# Scrapy in Python 2.7 v 3.6 - is there much of a difference?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm fairly new to Python and need to get proficient with Scrapy pretty quickly, so, I'm looking into purchasing a tutorial from Udemy. One of the tutorials I am looking at only covers Scrapy, on windows, with Python 2.7.

So, I am trying to determine if there is much of a difference between 2.7 and 3.6 and if it will be relatively straightforward to adapt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy supports both versions of Python with the same codebase, so you will have the same API and features no matter the platform. However, the code you write will be most likely written for a specific version of Python (unless it's **really** simple), so it comes down to Python2 vs Python3 and that's a different topic. A particular difference between both versions is Unicode handling (Python3 does it much better), and this is of big importance when doing web scraping.

My personal recommendation is that you start with Python3 and go with the official [Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) which will be up to date.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot matey!